# Object#tap question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why does

```
a = [].tap do |x|
  x << 1
end
puts "a: #{a}"
```

work as expected

```
a: [1]
```

but

```
b = [].tap do |x|
  x = [1]
end
puts "b: #{b}"
```

doesn't

```
b: []
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The 'tap' method on String object doesn't return expected result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331976/the-tap-method-on-string-object-doesnt-return-expected-result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the second snippet does not change the array is the same why this snippet:

```
def foo(x)
  x = [1]
end

a = []
foo(a)
```

does not change variable a. Variable x in your code is local to the scope of the block, and because of that you can assign anything to it, but the assignment won't be visible outside (Ruby is a pass-by-value language).

Of course, blocks have also closures on the local variables where they were declared, so this will work:

```
def foo(x)
  yield(x)
end

b = []
foo(123) do |x|
  b = [1]
end

p b # outputs [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first method put 1 on the end of an empty array. In the same way you cant say that an empty array is equal to 1. Rather you would try and replicate it...

```
b = [].tap do |x|
   x.unshift(1)
end
```

This is just an example yet have a look at the method call you can use on an Array by typing.

```
Array.methods.sort
```

All the best and Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly unrelated -- but that `[].tap` idiom is horrible. You should not use it. Even many of the people who used it in rails code now admit it's horrible and no longer use it.

Do not use it.

Comment: @artemave: because it's an abuse of `tap`. Tap was designed for tapping into a method chain (hence the name) or to keep a fluid interface going. The way `tap` is used in your code is neither DRYer nor more concise than the regular method, in fact i have no idea why you're doing it - it just looks like you're using `tap` for the sake of it. What's wrong with `x = []; x << 1` or indeed `[] << 1` (if you really want)

Comment: `tap` idiom is powerful - object construction. Scoped in a block and without temp variables to hold the result (where you don't need them after, say, if you immediately return the resulted object from a method). My example indeed uses `tap` for the sake of it but only to accompany the question.

Comment: @artemave....wait....why not use temp variables? what's the big deal about not using temp variables when: 1. you're not making it any more concise. 2. blocks are slow (this may be impt if performance is a requirement) 3. If you're returning from a method....why do you need to worry about "polluting" the scope with temporaries anyway? The scope dies immediately after you define the array so any temps are cleaned up.

Comment: no big deal, of course. Except for the part of making up a meaningful name for meaningless variable. I just hate it!